# Is it mandatory to sent synchronize message after pushing data to NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, synchronize

Just curious is it mandatory. For example in my app, I just push and get info from [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] without any need of "synchronize" call. Maybe I'm missing something but I haven't noticed any problems (YET) :). I know that this call should make synchronization between in memory and on disk data but why it is unnoticeable in my case?

Comment: AFAIK - if you won't synchronize and your app gets killed (by OS or by debugger), your changes won't be persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[synchronize](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize)

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals,
>   use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.

It's not mandatory, but if you update data and your app gets killed right after, you will lose information.

Comment: Right, that's why I didn't noticed that :). I think I will call it from the main app delegate method "applicationWillResignActive:"